# Nmap scan to get 2 random addresses with open port 80 in an IP prefix

Tags: nmap, network-scan

How can I use nmap to get 2 random addresses with open port 80 in an IP prefix. Nmap takes time for port scanning. Is there way to speed up the scanning?

Comment: `nmap` is used to enumerate an ip, how do you expect it to get `ip` as an output. It's not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got what you are asking but you just have to specify the port number to scan for and grep for open
if you need the ip address then use -B number of lines. Its not random but you could probably just pick out 2 of your choice if any at all?
nmap -p80 iprange | grep "open" -B 4